# REACT : how can i add break line in cell of row in csv file in react-csv

Tags: reactjs, csv

I want to create a break line on one of cell in my CSV file but I cant do this

my csv package is react-csv and I try this way :

```
rowResult.push([
          index + 1,
          cartData[item].title + '"' + attrs + '"',
        ]);
      });
```

result:
[image: result]
but I want this result :
[image: but I want this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it

must be used this way

> "\n"

```
rowResult.push([
          index + 1,
      cartData[item].title + '\n' + attrs + '\n',
        ]);
      });
```